Error de Cors en nodejs con react
Estoy haciendo un proyecto, un acortador de links.
Tengo los métodos de creacion del link corto y la redirección en mi backend, dejo adjunto mi método de redirección: 
¡Entonces desde el front-end al generar el link en el formulario te envía el link corto y te muestra el link para que tengas acceso 
Al acceder al link te envía a mí página de redirect.jsx donde llama al método de la primera foto y te debería redirigir a la página deseada, acá se ve la página redirect.jsx

Pero al intentar ingresar al lin recortado de google.com me sale este error de cors:

En mi back-end tengo puesto el código para cors así, dandole permisos a mi front-end:

Pensé no habría ningún problema con cors una vez puesto eso, pareciera que necesita los permisos de cada pagina a la que envian los links

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor aca. Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Me he encontrado con este problema multitud de veces y tras descubrir esta forma de evitarlo, se acabaron los molestos problemas de CORS.
El problema no radica en el cliente, sino en el servidor, mas concretamente, en tu configuracion CORS de app.js
Mi solucion seria la siguiente:
//CORS
const corsOptions = {
    origin: function(origin, callback){
        if(!origin || FRONTEND_URL === origin){
            callback(null, true)
        } else{
            callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS Policity"))
        }
    },
    credentials: true,
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions)) //Permitir que las peticiones del frontend, que estan en otro dominio, se puedan comunicar con el backend

En este caso, en vez de darle a origin directamente la direccion del cliente, le pasamos una funcion la cual no creo que necesite gran explicacion. (Si es asi, dejalo en los comentarios y la editare sin problema)
Aparte de esto, incluye un middleware el cual se aplicara a todas las rutas de tu aplicacion de express:
app.options("*", cors())

Espero haberte ayudado, como te comente anteriormente, esto me ha resuelto todos esos problemas. Aun asi, para cualquier duda no dudes en contactar!
Un saludo

Hola Roberto! No me estaria funcionando, aunque permita todas las rutas me sigue dando error de cors, hasta he probado app.use(cors()) y nada...

pero en app.use(cors()) estas incluyendo las corsOptions? Tal y como pone en la ultima linea del primer bloque de codigo.
Ademas, prueba a pasar la url del cliente con un String en vez de un .env para poder centralizar el error. Quedo a la espera

Sisi, lo hice con string y aun asi no funciona, lo puse tal cual mostraste `const corsOptions = {
origin: function (origin, callback) {
if (!origin || "http://localhost:5173" === origin) {
callback(null, true);
} else {
callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS Policity"));
}
},
credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options("*", cors());`
Probe intercalando entre los 2, con el que use yo y el problema persiste.
Usando el url del back-end manual funciona pero quiero que mi front-end lo redirija solo
